# Page redirection in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to redirect my login page to an admin page. I have specified the routes for the page as well as made the controller. However, when I run the login page, it redirects me to another page and not the one I was hoping for. Kindly help me sort this out.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'mainController@login']);
Route::post('/logs_in', 'mainController@logs_in');
Route::get('admin', [ 'as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'mainController@admin']);
```

mainController.php

```
 public function logs_in(Request $request){

    return redirect()->route('admin');
}



public function admin(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
```

login.blade.php

```
 <form action="/logs_in" method="post">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="checkbox icheck">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember Me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Log In</button>
    </div>
```

I am being redirected to /logs_in when I need to be redirected to /admin. Kindly help me find my error.

Comment: try doing return redirect('/admin');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `route('admin')` inside redirect.

```
public function logs_in(Request $request)
{

   return redirect(route('admin'));

}
```